# Navigate to login on 401

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I have an `API` service which wraps the common `Http` calls I would need. Basically just adding `Authorization` and `Content-Type` headers and converting the data. The request looks like this:

```
this.http.request(options.url, requestOptions)
  .map(this.unwrapHttpValue)
  .catch((error: any) => {
    if (error.status === 401) {
      this.errorsSubject.next(error);
    }
    return Observable.throw(error.status);
  });
```

In my app component I have subscribed to the error handler observable:

```
this.api.errors$
  .subscribe(() => {
    // ...
  });
```

So far so good. But when I add

```
this.router.navigate(['/login']);
```

inside the subscription, the redirect never happens, however, the URL is changed to `/login`. I'm kinda new to Angular 2 so I might be doing something wrong... or could it be something with the new router introduced in RCx? How can I work around this - and even if it worked, would it be an idiomatic solution?

**Edit:**

*Route definition*

```
{path: '/login', component: LoginComponent}
```

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? because it seems like the routing happens but the `/login` component doesn't get constructed

Comment: Well.. I can see an `EXCEPTION: 401` and `Uncaught 401`. That's all. Those shouldn't be a problem though, should they?

Comment: Try not to throw the 401 error, i.e. `if (error.status === 401){... return Observable.empty();}else{return Observable.throw(error);}`

Comment: Same thing, without those 2 "errors".

Comment: Would you include the route definition for `'/login'` in your question

Comment: I've edited the post. The `LoginComponent` at the moment is just creating a `ControlGroup` with `FormBuilder`, that's all it does.

Comment: The definition looks ok, if you try to access it directly, does it work ? like `http://localhost/login` ? also, try putting a `console.log` in the constructor of `LoginComponent` to see if it gets constrcuted

Comment: Yeah, it works directly, there's no problem with that. Added a `console.log` and that run. So it looks like it's the view only that is still rendered from the previous route.

Comment: it seems a zone issue, to make sure, import `NgZone` from `core` and run `console.log('is inside zone',NgZone.isInAngularZone())` just before you run `this.router.navigate(['/login'])`, if it outputs `is inside zone false`, it means you are navigating from outside angular zone and you need to fix that

Comment: It outputs `true`, "sadly".

Comment: I give up sorry, it will be helpful if you can reproduce it in a plunk

Comment: No problem! Thanks anyway! I'll try to create a plunk and come back with a link.

Comment: Weird thing is, it's working in plunker... Since it would've been a "workaround" for the missing *CanActivate* and it's not a production app anyway, I guess I'll just wait till it gets reintroduced.